# What does the word "treat" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the U.K. band Kasabian's song "Treat", there's a lyric like this:

> Everybody knows I work it work it like a treat

What's the meaning of the word *treat* in that phrase?

Comment: *It works a treat* is a British idiom meaning 'it works well'.

Answer (score 3):

OP's citation is a mash-up of two well-established usages...

> 1a: [*"it worked a treat"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22worked%20a%20treat%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22it%20worked%20a%20treat%22) (5230 hits in Google Books, primarily BrE)
>    and
>    1b: [*"it worked like a charm"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20worked%20like%20a%20charm%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (86300 hits)

For comparison, these are the "non-standard" versions...

> 2a: [*"it worked like a treat"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22worked%20a%20treat%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22it%20worked%20like%20a%20treat%22) (57 hits)
>    and
>    2b: [*"it worked a charm"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22worked%20a%20treat%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22it%20worked%20a%20charm%22) (145 hits)

---

The meaning is given by OED's definition 5b...

> **a treat** (adv.adj.)
>    *so as to gratify highly; **extremely well**;
>
>     also (gen. or ironically) extremely, excessively.*
>   colloquial

...where I've highlighted the most likely substitution appropriate for less colloquial contexts.

Comment: I'm most familiar with "it works(worked) like a treat", and less often "it works(worked) a treat". (US English).  And I've never heard it used to refer to oneself, but usually some mechanism or process.  No clue as to the origin.

Comment: @Hot Licks: OED cites *This air makes yer liver work a fair treat* from 1899. It's just a tiny shift (*syntactic*, rather than semantic) from ***treat** = desirable/pleasant experience*. All variations are usually reserved for contexts where you're being enthusiastic about something that's just happened to/for *you*, so you wouldn't normally say *"**I** worked a treat"*.

Comment: I’ll allow that the *treat* version might be mainly British, but not the *charm* one.

Comment: FumbleFingers and the Mashed Up Idioms. They'll never be as big as Fleetwood Mac.

Comment: @tchrist: I did wonder a bit about that as I was writing it. I'll take you at your word and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

"*I work it like a treat*," is equivalent to, "*I do it well*"