# Origin of "Works a treat"

Tags: etymology

Where does [*works a treat*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+a+treat) come from; is it related to sweets?
I cannot find any reference to its origin, are there words omitted such as *works [like] a treat*?

Comment: **— a treat 1** *informal* Used to indicate that someone or something does something specified very well or satisfactorily. *‘their tactics worked a treat’* https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/treat

Comment: **treat** is  "anything that affords much pleasure." https://www.etymonline.com/word/treat

Comment: So a treat in this context is a feeling and not derived from a thing?

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215975/what-does-the-word-treat-mean

Answer (score 1):

It probably derives from the slang meaning of ***[a treat](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/k44ruwq)*** as used in the following examples:

> - ***a treat***, 
>     also treato - 
>     [late 19C+] wonderfully, extremely, excessively, e.g. that’ll go down a treat.
> - In phrases
>     ***do one a treat*** (v.)
>     [late 19C+] to suit one absolutely.

(Green Dictionary of Slang)

The extension of the meaning of [treat](https://www.etymonline.com/word/treat) to something that gives pleasures dates back to the 18th century:

> - extention  Sense of "a treating with food and drink, an entertainment given as a compliment or expression of regard" (1650s) was extended by 1770 to "anything that affords much pleasure."

(Etymonline)

Comment: Not slang, just informal.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [related question/answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215975/what-does-the-word-treat-mean), it seems to be a variant usage; both *works a treat* and *works like a treat* are used, though (primarily in British usage) the former is far more common (by about two orders of magnitude).

*Treat* [is defined by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treat) as "an especially unexpected source of joy, delight, or amusement". So while a sweet would work as a treat, it is an example of a treat, but not itself the core meaning. If something *works [like] a treat*, it works very well, to the delight of the person who set this up.

A quick glance at websites reveals a common use in article headlines which report about some new investment or building project, change in behaviour or similar. It is usually used to positively evaluate the effectiveness of a remedy, behaviour, or project.

Comment: Yes but the question is: where does the expression come from? Why "a treat" means very well?

Comment: @user110518 because a _treat_ is something enjoyable, and if something works well, you derive enjoyment out of it. It does not mean 'very well' in other circumstances, _*I was eating like a treat_ does not mean "I was eating very well".

Comment: Yes, buy the question is about the origin of this usage.